# How to have a default value in the database but not in the form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm creating a registration form where a user inputs there address details. For the country field, i would like it to be defaulted to "united kingdom', in the database unless specified other wise, but i would like the form input to be blank. At the moment, it currently show "united kingdom' in the form. is it possible to do this?
I've already done the migrations for it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field

You can specify a value for the field:

```
<%= text_field :your_model, :country, value: '' %>
```

Hard to say exactly what you need since you haven't provided any code, but you could add validation that sets the value to 'United Kingdom' if the value of that field is `blank?`